# Is it OK to manually delete partition directories of hive tables from HDFS w/o dropping the partitions

Tags: hadoop, hive

Lets say I have a partitioned hive table

```
>show partitions db.my_table;
+----------------------------------+
|             partition            |
+----------------------------------+
|        in_date=20-09-2020        |
|        in_date=21-09-2020        |
|        in_date=22-09-2020        |
+----------------------------------+
```

If I manually delete the partition directories from HDFS by

```
$hadoop fs -rm -r 'path/to/table/in_date=20-09-2020';
```

but don't drop the partitions from hive table

Will it cause any real problem (apart for having orphaned partition names in the table meta data)?

### WHAT I HAVE VERIFIED

The hive table queries work fine (for both external and internal tables)

```
>select * from db.my_table;   --works fine
>show partitions db.my_table  --shows orphaned partitions,not a real problem
```

EDIT: Aggergate functions queries like COUNT(),MAX() etc fail with error

        *Input path does not exist: path/to/table/in_date=20-09-2020*

Does anyone know whether this might cause some other problem/break some other application?

Answer (score 1):

On Tez it causing FileNotFound Exception because partition metadata exists and folder is absent. Drop partition as well: `ALTER TABLE DROP PARTITION(in_date='20-09-2020')`

Answer (score 1):

TLDR: It will break applications as the metadata will indicate the partition is present which is false.

Long Answer:
Yes. Do it, if you hate yourself. Basically, any application on HDFS that will refer the metastore will find the partition and then attempt any activity on it. And when it tries to do that HDFS will blow up since it won't find the directory. So you will fail even if you succeed ( and no you won't be 'Baazigar' here ).